# Angular: Extract scope variables from expression

Tags: angularjs

How can I easily parse an angular expression to extract strings that represent a scope variable?
For example, given the expression 'networkId==2', how can I easily parse it and extract 'networkId' because it is a scope variable name.

The only way I can think of is to read each scope variable name and use a regular expression to find it in the angular expression.

Comment: Why would you do that? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I need to lookup the value of the scope variable in the expression.

Answer (score 0):

You want assign or compare value of scope variable? Anyway, after get the variable name by regular expression, you retrieve attribute value with $scope['name_atribute']

Comment: Yes, all I need to do is compare the value of the scope variable. Looks like  going regular expression is the way to go. Thanks.